# iOS Adding Image to Tableview Background View

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiview

I have a tableview that I am using to display data loaded from a web service. Sometimes it loads fast, other times it take awhile. While it's loading, the tableview just shows a blank screen (in my case it is a gray screen). I want to display in the tableview background view a simple image that says loading and has a loading icon that I will animate to spin, but I cannot get it to show up at all. Here is my code:

```
UIView *backgroundView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, self.view.bounds.size.height)];
[backgroundView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:227.0 / 255.0 green:227.0 / 255.0 blue:227.0 / 255.0 alpha:1.0]];

self.tableLoading.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"loading.png"];
self.tableLoading.frame = CGRectMake(145, 80, 30, 30);
[backgroundView addSubview:self.tableLoading];

[self.feedTableView setBackgroundView:backgroundView];
```

The background view shows up as expected, hence the gray background, but I CANNOT get the image to show up at all.

Any suggestions? This seems like a simple problem but I have already spent a long time at it with no success. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't think showing a background loading is a good user experience for a tableview, when content is in front. how often does that image have to load. perhaps hide the tableview until the image is ready?

Comment: The idea is to only show loading when there is no data for the table view. It is probably best to just hide the tableview until the data loads and add my image to the regular view and animate it. I very specifically want a simple custom activity indicator that just rotates an image while waiting for data, and then disappears when the data is loaded. This will ONLY happen when loading the view controller from my menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can avoid using your UIView and instead you can use an activity indicator.
Try something like this:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
    UIView *backgroundView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, self.view.bounds.size.height)];
    backgroundView.tag=1;
    [backgroundView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:227.0 / 255.0 green:227.0 / 255.0 blue:227.0 / 255.0 alpha:1.0]];

    self.tableLoading.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"loading.png"];
    self.tableLoading.frame = CGRectMake(145, 80, 30, 30);

    [backgroundView addSubview:self.tableLoading];
    [self.view addSubview:backgroundView];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    // Do your web service call asynchronous
        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            //All UI needs to be here, in this thread
            // remove from superview your loading image to show your tableview content
            for (UIView *subview in [self.view subviews]) {
                if (subview.tag == 1) {
                    [subview removeFromSuperview];
                }
            }
            [self.yourTableView reloadData];
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: That was what I originally started with but I want to have my own custom activity indicator that uses a simple image.

Answer (score 0):

How are you doing your webservice call? I suppose it's done on an asynchronous block. Maybe something like `AFNetworking` `NSOperation` block? If so, where are you setting the image as a background? All user interface (UI) stuff should not be done on a background thread, it should be done on the main thread since the main thread is the only one who should be involved to UI.

Try the following:

```
 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

    UIView *backgroundView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, self.view.bounds.size.height)];
    [backgroundView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:227.0 / 255.0 green:227.0 / 255.0 blue:227.0 / 255.0 alpha:1.0]];

    self.tableLoading.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"loading.png"];
    self.tableLoading.frame = CGRectMake(145, 80, 30, 30);
    [backgroundView addSubview:self.tableLoading];

    [self.feedTableView setBackgroundView:backgroundView];

});
```

You can start displaying the `UITableView` background image when you start the request, and just dismiss it right after the request is finishing networking.

For instance, `SLRequest` has a sending request method called `performRequestWithHandler:` which has a handler to be called when the request is done, within that handler, you can dismiss the custom indicator or remove it from your view controller.

Hope this help.

Comment: It's actually a twitter call using SLRequest. I basically just want to do a custom activity indicator in the middle of the screen when there is no tableview data and then when the data loads the tableview should automatically cover up the image and then I can get rid of it.

Comment: I updated my post, please have a look. I didn't used `SLRequest` before but I am sure it's the same idea around networking.